# Extracting a (variable) substring from filenames

Tags: bash

I have a large number of files with filenames of the format

OUTPUT_11_0.175

I want to extract the two numbers, I managed to get the second number with the following:

```
for file in ./dir/*; do
phi=${file##*_}
echo "$phi"
done
```

To get the other number 11 in this case, I tried

```
a=${file#*_}
```

but this returns everything to the left of the first underscore (the directory contains an underscore) - is there some way to convince bash to go to the read 'between' the two underscores and return '11'?

Comment: `set -- ${file//_/ }; echo "$2 $3"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ IFS=_ read -a foo <<< "OUTPUT_11_0.175"
$ echo "${foo[0]}"
OUTPUT
$ echo "${foo[1]}"
11
$ echo "${foo[2]}"
0.175
```

Comment: I found ~ http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html#HERESTRINGSREF helped me piece together what this meant.

Comment: It'd be nice to explain that `IFS=_` sets the Internal Field Separator to `_`, which will be used to split the herestring around `_` into a `foo` array